# #2054 Não é possivel fazer login no servidor MySQL - PhpMyAdmin - APACHE ( ERRO DE SENHA)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, phpmyadmin

Estava fazendo as configurações, na hora de instalar o mysql acabei colocando uma senha mas acabei errando acredito.

Agora na hora de logar no MyPhpAdmin - ele da este erro.

Estou Usando o Apache> segue imagens

[image: Pastas dos Arquivos]

[image: Tela do Apache]

[image: Erro MyPhpAdmin]

Sera que tem como mudar a senha, alguem consegue me ajudar, é que demorou para configurar e ja deu alguns outros erros mais pesados fiquei 3h quase procurando erros, e queria resolver só este erro simples pois deu este erro bem na ultima parte :(

Comment: Não lembro a minha senha, acredito que redefinindo ela ja daria certo

Comment: talvez este link te ajude, https://tekzoom.com.br/como-alterar-a-senha-do-mysql-do-xampp-e-do-phpmyadmin/

Comment: eu ate vi isso amigo, so que é Xaamp, ele abre diretao o cmd, como faço isso no Apache?

Comment: Windows10 64bit amigo.

Comment: abra o cmd e acesse o diretorio mysql\bin tente executar esse comando:mysql -u root SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('sua senha'); depois tente editar o arquivo config.default.php alterando o $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'sua senha'

Comment: Cara acho que e problema direto com o banco viu deu certo nao. Acho que vou reinstalar e dessa vez colocando Xaamp ou Waamp

Comment: consegui vlw,,j